# Problems with making a photo and save it to folder

Tags: android

Good day to everyone. Please help me solve the problem. When I click on the check mark, I constantly get 0 in it.result code and my photos are not saved. At the same time, before I did it in the wipe data emulator, everything worked. What could be the problem? What I do wrong?

[image]

**My MainActivity:**

```
private lateinit var activityResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
private lateinit var btnTakePicture: Button
private lateinit var etId: EditText


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    btnTakePicture = findViewById(R.id.btn_take_picture)
    etId = findViewById(R.id.et_id)

    activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        ActivityResultCallback {
            println(it.resultCode)
            if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK && it.data != null) {
                var bundle = it.data!!.extras
                var bitMap: Bitmap? = bundle?.get("data") as? Bitmap
            }
        })

    btnTakePicture.setOnClickListener {
        if (etId.text.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ID not filled in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            takePhoto()
        }

    }
}

private fun takePhoto() {
    var takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    var imagesFolder = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages")
    imagesFolder.mkdirs()
    var image = File(imagesFolder, etId.text.toString() + ".jpg")
    etId.text.clear()
    println("file was created + ${image.toString()}")
    var uriSavedImage = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        this, "com.nikita.doroshenko.facerecognizetest.fileprovider", image
    )
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage)
    activityResultLauncher.launch(takePictureIntent)
}
```

**Permissions in AndroidManifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Provider in AndroidManifest:**

```
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.nikita.doroshenko.facerecognizetest.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
```

And **file_paths** for Provider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="/" />
</paths>
```

**Update1:**

I change like this:

```
if (!imagesFolder.exists()) { 
 Toast.makeText(this, "Folder not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() 
 var checker = imagesFolder.mkdir() 
if (!checker) { 
 Toast.makeText(this, "Error with storage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() } }
```

Comment: `println("file was created + ${image.toString()}")` There was nothing in your code that created a file. (Which is ok ).

Comment: `imagesFolder.mkdirs()` Only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist. And if you call it then check the return value as it might fail and return false. If it returns false then stop after displaying a Toast to inform the user

Comment: Ok, understood. But don't understand what need to do with it. And how to save image to folder

Comment: And this raw, doesn't create file?       var image = File(imagesFolder, etId.text.toString() + ".jpg"

Comment: No. I already told you that . And it should not. Now please adapt your code around mkdir.

Comment: Yes, I receive false all the time. But why? I have permission for writer. It must create, right? And why if I created folder manually and remove mkdirs (because already have directory) it still doesn't save?

Comment: I change like this: 

if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Folder not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            var checker = imagesFolder.mkdir()
            if (!checker) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error with storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
But still don't understand what's wrong. Why it's not working and my resultCode always 0. Even I already have folder. Something wrong with file creation. Maybe I wrong with Provider in file_path.xml?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Updated post.

Comment: You are not returning or stopping if the directory cannot be created. Please put that code in your original code block and show that you stop or return. Also tell which Toasts you see. `if (!imagesFolder.exists()) if (!imagesFolder.mkdirs(){ Toast(......); return;} `. Please use this code.

Comment: `"Error with storage"` ??? Better: "Cannot create directory"`

Comment: `path="/"` Try: path="."

Comment: Ok I will try . except /. By the way, this guide is working fine https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.  But didn't understand what's big difference.